# grep is inconsistently defaulting to grep -P?

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables, grep

I have a script that does some housekeeping that works perfectly well when invoked from an interactive shell, but did nothing when invoked by cron. To troubleshoot this I started a shell with a 'blank' environment with the command:

```
env -i /bin/bash --noprofile --norc
```

Using this blank env I've dug into my script and found that the following `grep` will not match any files:

```
grep -il "^ws_status\s*=\s*[\"']remove[\"']$"
```

However, when run from an interactive shell the command will return the filenames of the matching files.

As a note, the expression is matching lines like: `WS_STATUS = "remove"`

Through trial-and-error I discovered that adding `-P` to the options [Perl regex] the command started working normally in the 'blank' shell. However, I have *no idea* why my login shell appears to be defaulted to `grep -P`.

- There is only one `grep` binary, `/bin/grep`
- There are no aliases defined for `grep=pgrep` or `grep="grep -P"`
- There is no env variable `GREP_OPTIONS` defined.

What's the deal here?

Note: OS is RHEL v5.10, Bash is v3.2.25, grep is v2.5.1

Comment: so in your interactive shell, `which grep` returns `grep -P`? Did you do a recursive grep for "grep -P" in `/etc/profile*`?

Comment: @PetterH `which grep` returns `/bin/grep`, and `grep -ri grep /etc/profile*` only prints out a few uses of it in the scripts.

Comment: Rather than `which grep` can you try `type grep`.

Comment: @MarkWagner `grep is hashed (/bin/grep)`

Comment: `which` is useless. What does `type -a grep` output? (note the `-a` option) Part of the reason for the difference in behavior is that an interactive shell often has a different `PATH` than the environment of `cron`.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson `grep is /bin/grep`. In both interactive and 'blank' shells.

Comment: OK, so what is it in `cron` (because `cron` isn't "blank").

Comment: @DennisWilliamson for the purpose of this question we can assume that the cron env and the 'blank' env are equivalent because: A) I was able to replicate the problem in the blank env. B) The solution in the blank env works in the cron env.

Comment: Sorry, I must have missed where the solution was posted. If you mean "adding -P" is the solution, then I disagree because the question is "what's the deal". By the way, `pgrep` is not at all the same as `grep -P`. `pgrep` searches for processes in the process list.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson crap, faulty assumption with grep/egrep/fgrep. Fixed the question title.

Comment: `\s` (and everything else in your pattern) is not `-P` specific in GNU `grep`. Try something that is: `echo 'cookbook' | grep --color 'o.*?'` Without the -P it shouldn't match anything, but with it all the o's should be matched. Try it in your interactive environment and your "blank" environment with and without the `-P`. (you missed a reference to `pgrep` when editing your question.)

Comment: @DennisWilliamson That works the same in both environments, so I guess it's not `-P`, but now I have even less of a clue what's happening. I also just did an `echo echo "^ws_status\s*=\s*[\"']remove[\"']$"` in both envs to see if it might have something to do with the escaping, but that's the same as well.

Comment: Are you 100% sure you are using the same shell in each environment? Sometimes cron runs sh while normal users run bash. Other times there might be a #! in a script you are running.

bash handles hash paths differently from sh & the ksh family can be different again (different set of built-ins)

Comment: @Ken all of my scripts begin with #!/bin/bash

Comment: I don't have enough rep to comment, but does it help if you use `\grep` with a backslash, instead of `grep`? I know you already said that it wasn't aliased, but in the off chance that it is, this should use an unaliased grep.

Comment: Is something setting the ````GREP_OPTIONS```` environment variable?

Comment: @JamesYoungman whatever the problem was I must have solved it way back when. It doesn't look like I've set anything in the environment. Re-reading the question I'm not even sure what the problem was, and the script has been running for the last couple years with `grep -ilP "^ws_status\s*=\s*[\"']remove[\"']"`.

Answer (score 2):

Are any of these variables et?

GREP_OPTIONS, LC_ALL, LC_COLLATE, LANG, LC_CTYPE, LC_MESSAGES or POSIXLY_CORRECT

Any of them could affect grep's behavior.

One thing you might try is "set -x" to see the individual commands that get run.  You might also move the commands into a shell script and call that from cron.  That way you can more easily add commands like `set`, `env`, and `set -x` more easily.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo SET
set
echo ENV
env
set -x
grep -il "^ws_status\s*=\s*[\"']remove[\"']$"
exit
```